# applications of product graphs

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I was reading a book http://imrich.at/books/handbook-of-product-graphs-second-edition/.

Under the section ***Preface*** it was written that:

> large
>   networks such as the Internet graph, with several hundred million hosts, can be efficiently
>   modeled by subgraphs of powers of small graphs with respect to the direct product.

Can anybody help me clearing the point where these product graphs are efficiently used in daily life? Thanks a lot.

Comment: The idea is probably two-fold. First, the properties of the product, and hence many of the properties of the subgraph, are determined by the properties of the small graphs, and small graphs are much easier to study. Secondly, in many large networds, like the Internet graph, nodes are in general directly connected to only a small part of the whole network, which means that local structure really is small-scale: the network as a whole is built up from relatively small local networks. However, this is not something about which I know very much.